# How to orchestrate a custom docker container run on multiple ec2 instances via sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have a file process_script.py, it looks as follows:

```
import argparse

if __name__=='__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--example_argument', type=str, help='Example argument description')

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
    
    print('Received arguments {}'.format(args))
```

The SageMaker example code is as follows:

```
import boto3, os, sagemaker
from sagemaker.processing import ScriptProcessor, ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
default_s3_bucket = sagemaker_session.default_bucket()

print(default_s3_bucket)


input_data = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path='./data_files', 
                                           bucket=default_s3_bucket)

role = get_execution_role()
script_processor = ScriptProcessor(command=['python3'],
                image_uri='ecr/docker_image:latest',
                role=role,
                instance_count=1,
                base_job_name = 'run-processing',
                instance_type='ml.c5.xlarge')

output_location = os.path.join('s3://',default_s3_bucket, 'processing_output')

script_processor.run(code='process_script.py',
                     arguments=['--example_argument', 'value'],
                     inputs=[ProcessingInput(source=input_data,destination='/opt/ml/processing/input')],
                     outputs=[ProcessingOutput(source='/opt/ml/processing/output',destination=output_location)]
                    )
```

How can I use SageMaker ScriptProcessor following the above example, to schedule each run of the process_script.py file with custom arguments on different ec2 instances? I know I would have to change the "instance_count=1", but it is not clear how to orchestrate the runs on multiple ec2 instances using the SageMaker.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker processing can be used to run parallel jobs by increasing the instance count with each instance using different data from S3. For input data you can use shardbys3key (https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.ProcessingInput)  to split the data files among different nodes. The same script will be run on each instance with different data files sharded by s3key.

If you want to do distributed processing you can use something like dask to run the processing - https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/sagemaker_processing/spark_distributed_data_processing